# Replace a few values of an array of objects and leave other unchanged

Tags: javascript

I have the following two arrays:

```
let myArray = [{"id": 0, "creator":"Foo", "title":"title1", "message":"message1"}, {"id":1,"creator":"Bar", "title":"title", "message":"message2"}];

const payload = {"creator":"creator3", "title":"title3", "message":"message3"};
```

Knowing the index already, I would like to change only the creator, title and message parameters, leaving the id unchanged.

I have the following:

```
[myArray[0].creator, myArray[0].title, myArray[0].message] = [payload.creator, payload.title, payload.message];
```

I would like to know, is there a more elegant way to accomplish this? I was trying to somehow destructure this, but it looks like it may not be possible?

I would really appreciate any hints.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really want to update the first item only or the whole array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using simple destructuring:

```js
const myArray = [{"id": 0, "creator":"Foo", "title":"title1", "message":"message1"}, {"id":1,"creator":"Bar", "title":"title", "message":"message2"}];

const payload = {"creator":"creator3", "title":"title3", "message":"message3"};

const Changeindex = 0;

myArray[Changeindex] = {...myArray[Changeindex],...payload};

console.log(myArray)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
Object.assign(myArray[0], payload);
```

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const myArray = [
  {"id": 0, "creator":"Foo", "title":"title1", "message":"message1"},
  {"id":1,"creator":"Bar", "title":"title", "message":"message2"}
];

const payload = {"creator":"creator3", "title":"title3", "message":"message3"};

Object.assign(myArray[0], payload);

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateObjectProperties(obj, newValues) {
  for (const key in newValues) {
    if (key in obj) {
      obj[key] = newValues[key];
    }
  }
}
let myArray = [{"id": 0, "creator":"Foo", "title":"title1", 
"message":"message1"}, {"id":1,"creator":"Bar", "title":"title", 
"message":"message2"}];

const payload = {"creator":"creator3", "title":"title3", "message":"message3"};

console.log(myArray[0]);
updateObjectProperties(myArray[0], payload);
console.log(myArray[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution being a one-liner already can hardly be shortened any further. You could, however, write it in a different way, involving a `.forEach()` loop:

```
["creator","title","message"].forEach(p=>myArray[0][p]=payload[p])
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try this,

```
let myArray = [{"id": 0, "creator":"Foo", "title":"title1", 
"message":"message1"}, {"id":1,"creator":"Bar", "title":"title",     "message":"message2"}];

const payload = {"creator":"creator3", "title":"title3", "message":"message3"};

const index = 0; // specify the index you want to update

myArray[index] = {
  ...myArray[index], // keep other properties unchanged
  ...payload // update specified properties
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elegant way to do this:

```
const index = 0; // The index of the object you want to update
const { creator, title, message } = payload;
myArray[index] = { ...myArray[index], creator, title, message };
```

```js
let myArray = [
  {"id": 0, "creator":"Foo", "title":"title1", "message":"message1"},             {"id":1,"creator":"Bar", "title":"title", "message":"message2"}
];

console.log("Original Array:");
console.log(myArray);


const payload = {"creator":"creator3", "title":"title3", "message":"message3"};

const index = 0; // The index of the object you want to update
const { creator, title, message } = payload;
myArray[index] = { ...myArray[index], creator, title, message };

console.log("Updated Array:");
console.log(myArray);
```